# Cómo obtener la coincidencia encontrada con includes?

Tags: javascript

Si en un `Array`, busco algún elemento con `includes`, envés de devolver un booleano, como puedo devolver la coincidencia, **osea cual fué el elementro encontrado**?

```js
var a = ["eeuu","usa"];
var b = "eeuu";
var c = a.includes(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `indexOf` en lugar de `includes` para obtener el índice del elemento buscado dentro del array:

```js
var a = ["eeuu","usa"];
var b = "eeuu";

// true/false indicando si existe
var includes = a.includes(b);
console.log(includes);

// índice del elemento buscado
var index = a.indexOf(b);
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar:

```
var a = ["eeuu","usa"];
var b = "eeuu";

if(a.includes(b)){
   console.log(b)
}
```

Código completo con una función:

```js
 var a = ["eeuu","usa"];
    var b = "eeuu";

    function muestraCoincidencia(array,elementoBuscado){
        if(array.includes(b)) return b; 
    }

    var palabra_buscada = muestraCoincidencia(a, b);
    console.log(palabra_buscada);
```